# How to develop Editable dropdownlist(Selection list) in asp.net mvc3 with out using Jquery ,Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to do Dropdownlist in my application .it should allow user to select and enter value into that.So please try help me how to do Editable Dropdown list with out using Jquery and Ajax

Thanks

Comment: Yes,java script is allowed,iam using asp.net Mvc3 but my client dont want use Jquery and ajax..So help me with out those

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? Is there something we could help you with?

Comment: Actually iam new to MVC3 So please try to help with code..already iam able bind data from DB to dropdown but as well as i want give provision to user to enter his own values to that dropdown..how?